Port forwarding doesn't work on home router
I have a tplink archer ax50, no modems no nothing, just the router, and i want set up port forwarding. I create the virtual private server as it's called here, I run nmap on the local ip of the host and the port is opened but when i try to access the port on the public ip it doesn't work.
I have windows 11 on my host machine
I made sure that the local ip address of the host is static, made sure that the wan ip address of the router is public not private, set up firewall rules and even disabled firewall on the host to test and i still can't get it to work. I also ran wireshark on the host to look for traffic to that specific port and nothing. I know it's not because of the ISP because i did this before and it worked just fine but now i can't seem to get it to work anymore.
If i missed any information that i need to put here please let me know

Are you doing the tests from inside or outside? How did you check the WAN IP address?

I tried both from inside and outside, using the local ip addresses and the public one, tried from a different network and i still got nothing, it only worked on the same network with the local addresses. For the WAN i used both the address from the router configuration page on the internet page and the one from whatismyip still without any results

You can only test this if you are actually outside of the network yourself and then connect to the WAN IP. For example, use your mobile phone, disable wifi and try to connect then. That should work.
